# Ошибка при push GitHub

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push

При попытки первого пуша на ГитХаб вылезает ошибка. Ранее с этого ПК еще не пушил, не пойму в чем проблема.

При вводе git push -u origin master , подтверждаю , но потом появляется следуещее:

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: в origin у вас что находится?

Comment: Прошу прощения, но я так думаю ничего. Действую по инструкции с ГитХаба

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить проблему. Попробовал повзоимодействовать через декстопную версию ГитХаба, и всё получилось. Далее при использовании пуша в консоли на этот раз поступил запрос о "коннекте" Гита с браузером и после этого ошибки уже не возникало.

Answer (score 0):

при общении программы *git* с сервером(-ами) могут быть использованы [разные протоколы](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B). строка «Host key verification failed» явно свидетельствует о том, что в вашем случае использовался протокол *ssh*.

протокол *ssh* подразумевает аутентификацию в том числе и «той стороны»: при первом же соединении вам предлагается сохранить публичный ключ «той стороны» (в файле `~/.ssh/known_hosts`). а при каждом последующем соединении передаваемый «той стороной» ключ сверяется с сохранённым. если они не совпадают — программа *ssh* и выдаёт вам сакраментальную ошибку:

> Host key verification failed

причин несоответствия может быть много. вот далеко не полный их список (порядок пунктов произвольный):

- очень «хитрый» сетевой сбой, при котором повредилось именно содержимое переданного публичного ключа. пожалуй, очень редкое явление.
- [атака посредника](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) (mitm, man in the middle). ещё большая, пожалуй, редкость, особенно если ни сервер ни клиент не попадают в сферу каких-нибудь корпоративных/государственных интересов.
- неправильно настроенный dns-сервер, который преобразовал сетевой имя в ip-адрес совсем не той машины, к которой вы хотели подключиться.
- машина та, что нужна, просто на ней администратор перегенерировал её секретный (а соответственно, и публичный) ключ. ну, к примеру, работает она внутри docker-контейнера, который был перезапущен.

в последнем из перечисленных вариантов можно банально удалить сохранённый (в файле `~/.ssh/known_hosts`) публичный ключ «той стороны». примерно так:

```
$ ssh-keygen -R сетевое.имя.«того».сервера
```